# Oracle OCI and Thin drivers are missing in SQuirreL SQL

Tags: oracle-call-interface, ojdbc, squirrel-sql

I downloaded [**SQuirreL SQL**](http://squirrel-sql.sourceforge.net/) and I want to use it as an Oracle client, but when I go to **Drivers** tab, the following jars are missing:

- Oracle OCI Driver
- Oracle Thin Driver

  [image: Drivers OCI and Thin Driver]

How can I fix this problem?

Answer (score 20, accepted):

1. Download [**ojdbc7.jar**](http://download.oracle.com/otn/utilities_drivers/jdbc/121010/ojdbc7.jar)

   - you need an Oracle account, but the e-mail is the only important detail that you need to provide (you can add any characters for Work Phone, Company Name, etc.)
2. Go to the SQuirreL SQL installation folder (E.g.: C:\Program Files\squirrel-sql-3.7.1) > **lib** and put **ojdbc7.jar** there.
3. Restart SQuirreL SQL.

Comment: This worked for me on macOS 11 (Big Sur) as well. I placed the driver file in the following location: /Applications/SQuirreLSQL.app/Contents/Resources/Java/lib/

Answer (score 4):

The file **ojdbc7.jar** has to be downloaded from the following page, as you **must** accept the license agreement: https://www.oracle.com/technetwork/database/features/jdbc/jdbc-drivers-12c-download-1958347.html

Note that you are not requested to log in nor to provide your email address.